# What's the difference between $f'(x)$ and $ f(x)'$?

Tags: calculus

let $f(x)=x^2$
Is there a difference between writing $f(5)'$ or $f'(5)$?

I suppose the the first gives $0$ while the second gives $10$. is that right?

Comment: I would interpret $f(5)’$ as the derivative of the constant $f(5)$, and thus set it equal to $0$; while $f’(5)$ would be the value of the derivative of $f$ at $5$. That said, I’ve never seen the former! I would write it as $(f(5))’$ to make sure there is no possible confusion...

Comment: Yes, the the first gives 0 while the second gives 10. Generally though, $f(5)′$ seems strange to me. I agree with Arturo that I would write $(f(5))'$ for disambiguation.

Comment: I have not seen $f(5)'$ except in an assignment written by a beginning student.

Comment: We can write $[x^2 + 2x+5]' = 2x+2$ to avoid going to the function store and spend hard earned money on a variable $f$ jsut so we can say if $f(x)=x^2 + 2x + 5$ the $f'(x)=2x+2$.  When we have $[WHACKADOO]'$ it means treat $WHACKADOO$ as a function (presumably of $x$ although it's not explicitly stated) and take its derivative.  As a result we have to shrug and assume when we see $f(5)'$ then means $[f(5)]'$ so take $f(5)=25$ and treat it as a function... well it's a constant so $[25]'=\frac {d25}{dx}=0$...we gotta reach that conclussion. (conclussion=a conclusion that hits you on the head)

Comment: @GEdgar or as a mean instructor trying to pound home a point... like we are doing.... But, yes, whereever the OP ran across this, the intent of writing "$f(5)'$" was almost certainly a mistake and they probably meant "$f'(5)$".

Comment: To sum it up, $f(5)'$ is basically nonsense and shouldn't be used. In my own work, I try to avoid using the prime notation as much as possible unless it is extremely clear what the type and variable of differentiation is - I pretty much only use the prime notation when talking about total derivatives of single variable functions. That's because not only is the prime notation ambiguous, but the prime symbol has many other uses as well, for instance when talking about two different reference frames with position vectors $\mathbf{r}$ and $\mathbf{r}'$

Answer (score 1):

When we speak about derivative, it is of a function. the derivative of a real doesn't mean anything. Instead of $ f(5)' $, we must write

$$(x\mapsto f(5))'$$
and
$$(x\mapsto f(5))'(x)=0$$

on the other hand, $ f'(5) $ is the value of the derivative $ f' $ at the point $ x=5$ well defined by
$$f'(5)=\lim_{x\to 5}\frac{f(x)-f(5)}{x-5}$$
$$=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h+5)-f(5)}{h}$$

Comment: It is pretty common to identify the constant functions with the reals. In that case, $f(5)' = 0$.

Comment: If $f(x) = c$ is a constant function then $f'(x) = 0$.  Even beginners should know that.  So if $f(5) = 25$ is a constant.  Then the constant function $g(x) =25$ has derivative equal to $0$.  I have to disagree with you and stat the derivative of a real makes *perfect* sense.  But such a derivative is always  $0$.

Comment: @fleablood Watch out, we don't have $g=25$, we have $g(x)= 25$ for all $x$ and you can take the derivative of $g$ Which is $0$. Taking the derivative of a real makes sense of you identify reals with constant functions, but they are a priori not the same thing.